# Mahout Canopy clustering example

Tags: mahout

I'm trying to figure out Canopy clustering from an example Synthetic control data in Apache Mahout Cookbook. But, instead of getting 6 clusters as as result, I get 600 - one for each sample in the set.

C-0{n=1 c=[0:28.781, 1:34.463, 2:31.338, 3:31.283, 4:28.921, 5:33.760, 6:25.397, 7:27.785, 8:35.248, 9:27.116, 10:32.872, 11:29.217, 12:36.025, 13:32.337, 15:34.525, 16:32.872, 17:34.117, 18:26.524, 19:27.662, 20:26.369, 21:25.774, 22:29.270, 25:30.733, 26:29.505, 27:33.029, 28:25.040, 31:28.917, 32:24.344, 33:26.120, 34:34.942, 35:25.029, 36:26.631, 37:35.654, 38:28.435, 39:29.150, 40:28.158, 41:26.193, 42:33.318, 43:30.977, 44:27.044, 45:35.534, 46:26.235, 47:28.996, 48:32.004, 49:31.056, 50:34.255, 51:28.072, 52:28.940, 53:35.497, 54:29.747, 56:31.433, 57:24.556, 58:33.743, 59:25.047, 60:34.932] r=[]}

C-1{n=1 c=[0:24.892, 1:25.741, 3:27.553, 4:32.822, 5:27.879, 6:31.593, 7:31.486, 8:35.547, 9:27.952, 10:31.660, 11:27.542, 12:31.189, 13:27.487, 14:31.391, 16:27.811, 18:24.488, 20:27.592, 21:35.627, 22:35.410, 23:31.417, 24:30.745, 25:24.131, 26:35.142, 27:30.472, 28:31.987, 29:33.662, 30:25.551, 31:30.469, 32:33.647, 33:25.070, 34:34.077, 35:32.598, 36:28.304, 37:26.147, 38:26.941, 39:31.520, 40:33.109, 41:24.149, 42:28.516, 43:25.791, 44:35.952, 45:26.530, 46:24.858, 47:25.956, 48:32.836, 49:28.532, 50:26.346, 51:30.621, 52:28.986, 53:29.405, 54:32.558, 55:31.021, 56:26.642, 57:28.433, 58:33.656, 59:26.424, 60:28.466] r=[]}

C-2{n=1 c=[0:31.399, 1:30.632, 2:26.398, 3:24.291, 4:27.861, 5:28.549, 6:24.972, 7:32.436, 8:25.224, 9:27.307, 10:31.839, 11:27.259, 12:28.257, 13:26.582, 14:24.046, 15:35.063, 16:31.572, 17:32.561, 18:31.031, 19:34.120, 20:26.934, 21:31.478, 22:35.017, 23:32.385, 24:24.332, 25:30.200, 26:31.245, 27:26.681, 28:31.514, 29:28.878, 30:27.309, 31:24.246, 33:26.963, 34:25.292, 35:31.611, 36:24.713, 37:27.481, 38:24.208, 39:26.806, 40:35.125, 41:32.629, 42:31.056, 43:26.358, 44:28.086, 45:31.439, 46:27.306, 47:29.608, 48:35.973, 49:34.144, 50:27.172, 51:33.632, 52:26.597, 53:25.539, 54:32.543, 55:25.577, 56:29.990, 57:31.351, 59:33.900, 60:29.545] r=[]}

C-3{n=1 c=[0:25.774, 2:30.526, 3:35.421, 4:25.603, 5:27.970, 8:25.270, 9:28.132, 11:29.427, 12:31.455, 13:27.320, 16:28.956, 17:28.992, 18:29.958, 19:30.277, 20:30.445, 21:24.304, 22:24.314, 24:35.097, 25:25.368, 26:32.097, 27:33.330, 28:25.010, 29:35.316, 30:31.626, 31:29.281, 32:34.202, 33:26.508, 34:32.228, 35:25.527, 36:24.824, 38:27.559, 39:28.371, 40:32.367, 41:26.975, 42:35.935, 43:35.115, 44:24.375, 45:27.608, 46:27.843, 47:29.856, 48:32.419, 49:26.891, 50:31.321, 51:29.385, 52:34.334, 53:24.738, 54:35.769, 56:31.873, 57:34.205, 58:31.156, 60:34.629] r=[]}

And so on, until C-600.

Can anyone think of a reason?

I am using

```
mahout canopy -i $WORK_DIR/sequencefile/synthetic_control.seq -o
                 $WORK_DIR/output/canopy.output -t1 80 -t2 55
```

I'm using Mahout 0.9 running on Hadooop 1.2.1. Example from the book is for 0.9 version of Mahout, is there a change in the way of calling the function?

I even tried using different values of t1 and t2, but the results are same.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this ? I am getting similar results for each sample in set.

Answer (score 0):

Canopy WAS used to create a guess for the parameter "K" in Kmeans. It was so sensitive to the choice of t1 and t2 that is has been useless IMO. Therefore it's being deprecated.

There isn't a good alternative in Mahout but you can look at streaming kmeans or try using clusterdump on the results of kmeans and find the best k fit for your real data that way, looking for highest cohesion and greatest separation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if I don't now how many clusters is needed, and I'm adding the data dynamically, so the structure, and the number of clusters could change? I'm trying to use it for anomaly detection, in a way that if the new point does not belong to a cluster, it is considered as an anomaly. What can I use then as an  alternative? I am a beginner in this field, so any advice would be great. I don't now about this streaming kmeans, but I saw on their site that it is not stable enough yet...